# Where can I obtain more weather data?

Tags: data-mining, dataset

Where can I obtain more weather data?

NOAA has some:

- http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/DF.an/DC.sflnd/DS.synop/
- http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/DF.an/DC.sflnd/DS.metar/
- http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/DF.an/DC.sfmar/DS.dbuoy/
- http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/SL.us008001/DF.an/DC.sfmar/DS.ships/

but I also want amateur observations. Specifically:

- Where can I get APRS WX data? I know that "telnet rotate.aprs.net 
  10152" with "user READONLY pass -1" will give me lots of 
  information, but:

  - Can I filter it down to just weather reports?
  - Is this all APRS WX data, or just a subset?
- wunderground.com has over 17K stations 
  at http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/index.asp reporting to 
  them. Is this data available publicly on some "free weather exchange 
  network"? I realize I can get it from wunderground.com, but would 
  prefer a "legit" source.
- Are there other sources of weather data out there? Is there any 
  one source that conglomerates multiple other sources?

Recently found RAWS: http://raws.wrh.noaa.gov/rawsobs.html but sense there is more

Comment: How is wunderground not "legit"? It apparently has nothing to do with amateur observations, which you want, but what is it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that wunderground recruits people to report directly to them, so I don't see how you'd do that. And I'm not sure what the difference would be. Are you looking for more details than you can get through them?

Comment: It turns out you're right. wunderground confirmed they are primary. Maybe there are no other sources?!

Comment: @barrycarter I think wunderground has an API that amateur meteorologists post directly to.  It's easy to download a .csv file of weather observations for a specific station, and you could write a script to loop through a bunch of dates and download data for a station.

Comment: Wundergound collects data from amateurs who have weather stations that meet certain standards.  As Zach says, you can scrape the data off of their websites for personal / occasional, use, but if you want to use a lot of data or for commercial use you (should) pay for it.  You get regular uploads of the weather station data you subscribe to, maybe daily IIRC.  A lot of radio and TV stations subscribe to WUG, and pay the appropriate (not very great) fees.

Comment: @Zach I actually tried this once (https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/f91eeabc1db03c5ee8ea372d839dc4a4d86c00e2/bc-generic-voronoi.pl), but there are too many of them, even using parallel (plus, wunderground.com appears to limit simultaneous connections), so I just do local ones for now. If there were a single source that summarized current reports for all stations, that would be useful.

Comment: @jbowman I've seen more anomalies with wunderground.com personal weather station data than I have with other sources. It's true that submitters must have an approved weather station, but the siting/location of a weather station can have a lot to do with its accuracy.

Comment: @barrycarter - I have too, you definitely have to pick your stations and look at their history to see if there are long blank periods or just plain obviously wrong data.

Comment: @barrycarter: "If there were a single source that summarized current reports for all stations, that would be useful."  I agree.  I've never found one, but will post here if I do!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding sources of data.